# Resize Image on addeventlistener function

Tags: javascript, image, resize, addeventlistener, event-listener

I'm trying to resize an image using addEventListener. I searched for this question and found similar ones but I haven't been able to make the function work properly.

The following code demonstrates a working function that resizes the image.

```
    header.onload=function(){
        var fullHeaderWidth=this.width
        if(fullHeaderWidth>window.innerWidth)
            header.width=window.innerWidth;

        setInterval(function(){
            if(fullHeaderWidth>window.innerWidth)
                header.width=window.innerWidth;
            else
                header.width=fullHeaderWidth;   
        },50)
    };
```

But when I try to use this function...

```
    var header=new Image();
    header=document.getElementById('header');
    header.onload=function(){
        var fullHeaderWidth=this.width
        if(fullHeaderWidth>window.innerWidth)
            header.width=window.innerWidth; 
    };
    header.src='file:///C|/Users/Dillon/Development/Jesses Works/header.gif'

    window.addEventListener('resize',function(){
        if(fullHeaderWidth>window.innerWidth)
            header.width=window.innerWidth;
        else
            header.width=fullHeaderWidth;   
    },false)
```

The event fires (I know this because I used alert in the function), but the image will not resize. Any ideas?

Comment: `fullHeaderWidth` isn't defined

Comment: Where is the `addEventListener`?

Comment: Sorry I cited that incorrectly this is the full script:
`var header=new Image();
header=document.getElementById('header');
header.onload=function(){
 var fullHeaderWidth=this.width
 if(fullHeaderWidth>window.innerWidth)
  header.width=window.innerWidth; 
 },50)
};
header.src='file:///C|/Users/Dillon/Development/Jesses Works/header.gif'

window.addEventListener('resize',function(){
  if(fullHeaderWidth>window.innerWidth)
   header.width=window.innerWidth;
  else
   header.width=fullHeaderWidth; 
},false)`

Comment: There's an extra bracket in my last comment but the code was edited in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting confused, I think you're trying to do something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        var fullHeaderWidth = this.width;
        if (fullHeaderWidth > window.innerWidth) {
            header.width = window.innerWidth;
        } else {
            header.width = fullHeaderWidth;
        }
    }, 50);
});
```